# How can I add a column with comments to an Excel file after processing rows using a dynamic file path in Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow which runs when a file is placed on a folder.

[image]

I have a done a  bunch of transformation in the loop based on a job id as key..
Once it processed i want to update  a column with comments as Processed for the same excel which i have used.

I am using add rows to table action with my dynamic file path and the table name . As i cant see the columns i couldn't able to map.

I did tried giving the column name and the value it should updated but it's not working , Can any one please help me out of this?

[image]

I want to Add a column to the processed excel for each row